# XML changing values in elements

Tags: xml

I have some XML data that looks like, I am trying to modify the X Y and CX and CY values across about 20 different XML's to be exactly double the current value.

```
<Label item="ADLW_PLLLbl">
<ScreenID>ADLW_PLLLbl</ScreenID>
<Location>
  <X>5</X>
  <Y>5</Y>
</Location>
<Size>
  <CX>105</CX>
  <CY>24</CY>
</Size>
<Text>Personal Loot</Text>
<TextColor>
  <R>255</R>
  <G>255</G>
  <B>255</B>
</TextColor>
```

Comment: What language are you trying to work with in order to alter all these XML documents? I recommend you edit your question and add in what language you want and what you've tried so far.

Comment: To be honest I am a Complete noob its and XML for a UI of a Game a I play. I kind of understand what i want to do is double the values of certain things to making a UI meant for 1080p screen fit on a a 2560p screen. The UI is written in XML and can be found here. http://www.eqinterface.com/downloads/fileinfo.php?id=4620

Comment: Do you have any programming experience? Or are you looking for someone to make a todo this? My recommendation would be to edit these  values manually in a text editor because it would probably take someone longer to make a script todo it, then it would to edit the files.

Comment: If you are not using any code/programming language to update these values, then it would be a good amount of manual work. In that case, I would say, download and install Notepad++, and then search and replace the text using Notepad++ for all files in a folder. My two cents!